# Style sheets not rendering in Mac OS SIERRA and IOS10

Tags: css, macos, stylesheet, ios10, macos-sierra

I have some issues of style sheets not being rendered correctly or not rendered at all when using Safari browser on MAC OS SIERRA or IOS10.
Is this issue related to SIERRA bugs ? Is there anything that needs to be done from my side to maybe amend my CSS and LESS file to be compatable with SIERRA and IOS10 ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Sierra is not the problem. Are you sure the stylesheet is properly loaded ? You can see this in the network tab (select stylesheets and reload your page).

Comment: I'm having a similar problem on my Mac Pro, but not my Mac Mini or MacBook Pro; it's also affecting anything Safari downloads past a certain size.  Everything seems to work fine in FireFox, but Chrome has the same problems Safari does.  I've even reformatted, reinstalled, run diagnostics and memtest--I'm fairly certain it's not my hardware.